# Где достать приложение для пинтерест?

Tags: веб-программирование

Совершенно случайно, ни у кого нет одобренного приложения для пинтерест, может быть когда то создавали?

Они раньше всем одобряли доступ к доскам и пинам, сейчас прекратили, очень нужно приложение. Про приложения я говорю вот с этой страницы: [developers.pinterest.com](https://developers.pinterest.com/apps/)

Я уже обыскал все форумы, не думал, что это вызовет такую сложность.

Comment: А чего не хватает в ["API">"Getting Started"](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/overview/)?

Comment: То, что я создал приложение для меня оно работает, но что бы добавить пользователей, нужно пройти проверку, они запускают какую то там платформу и теперь не одобряют приложения которые хотят размещать пины, например блогеры.

Comment: "Не одобряют" = "отказывают"? Как отказ мотивируется? Желательно, цитатой.

Comment: Unfortunately, in order to avoid confusion with our Marketing Partners program, we currently do not allow marketing platforms to use our developer API. This includes (but isn’t limited to) services that are meant to help marketers, advertisers or digital publishers (e.g. bloggers) report on, manage, distribute or optimize the digital marketing for paid or organic media. For more information about this use case restriction, please see our developer guidelines

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он связан с внутренними политиками Pinterest, а не техническими затруднениями.

Comment: Да, но они официально разрешают работать старым приложениям и не собираются применять к ним какие то ограничения, если кто то был бы готов поделиться, я не думаю, что это нарушит их правила? Портить из платформу я не собираюсь.

Comment: Это решать уже Pinterest. Здесь даются воспроизводимые ответы для широкой публики. Для широкой публики Pinterest запрещает делать приложения маркетинговой направленности, поэтому воспроизводимого ответа на ваш вопрос нет.